# Dynamic variable in async function

Tags: c#

I need a local dynamic variable in some async function

```
 public async Task SomeFunction()
    {
      dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(@"{'someJSON': 'value'}"); 
    }
```

In the Watch window, its type is displayed as an object

```
**object**{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

If I remove the async modifier, the variable is dynamic as expected.

```
**dynamic**{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

If it's dynamic I can use a dot syntax liked.someJSON.
If it's the object I'm getting an error - someJSON does not exist.

I checked different C# version, but getting the same result.

Is this by design? How do I get a real dynamic in asyn function?

Comment: I should first make the disclaimer, 99.99 percent of the time, if you find your self using dynamic the design probably needs to be rethought

Comment: I prefer to deserialize JSON into dynamic.   d.FieldName is much more convinient then d["FieldName"]

Comment: Is there an actual problem here, or is this only a watch window thing. in both cases, the compiler treats them as a boxed int, so its possibly just a tooling issue

Comment: Dynamic is not a type; it is a keyword that tells the compiler how to treat a variable. The actual type of the variable is determined by what you assign; in your example, you are assigning `1`, so the variable is a `System.Int32`.  And [I cannot reproduce the behavior you are reporting](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mJ4rtG)

Comment: The variable is actually not dynamic if async.

Comment: Check it out [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACg5dgxBWNdKAZgQCY4BhOAbwy21KgA4EA2OAZQHsBbAUyh4ALgEtuAOwAUASnoM6mBsrjAAnhICGvUQGNVcALxwU8ldkQBOKcBmFzDKJfYA6ACL8ANprVTEdhzM4AF8g5RJsDh4BITFJMlkgxQcsdS0dfWAjE3sUpGtbXIcoAHZXD29ff2RApSxQuoQmABY4AFlZWiCG4KA)  You will notice `private object <d>5__1;` and `object arg = 1;` respectively

Comment: @PaulB. what is this stopping you from doing, i mean your comment, "*The variable is actually not dynamic if async*" what cant you do exactly

Comment: When I deserialize JSON into dynamic varibale I can't acess object fields by dot syntax.

Comment: @PaulB. please specify error which you unexpectedly get when using `dynamic`. I mean *In the Watch window, its type is displayed as an object object{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}* is not an error per se. Have you tried using dot notation to access fields? If so, what exception do you get?

Comment: Well, I'm getting error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'someJSON' and no extension method 'someJSON' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.  But this happens only if I check expression  d.someJSON in Watch. 
In a real code it works as expected. Seems to be a debugger glitch. Thanks all

Comment: In an async method, the local variable is lifted onto a generated type as a field, most likely the debugger just gets confused and is missing some metadata. The async and iterator code rewriting part of the compiler can throw the debugger for a loop sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be a debugger glitch. The issue happens only in a debug window. Thanks all.